# Drawing overlay in android using foreground service

Tags: android, overlay, foreground-service

I'm trying to draw an overlay over the android phone using my application so that I can draw a stroke over the edges of the android phone with a color using the custom view. But when I pass it the flag of WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY it works fine but it only draw the border under the status bar while I want to draw it on the whole screen of the phone on the status bar too. So I have did some research and it said that I should use WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT, so when I tried to use this flag the app crashes with and error of permission denied 2003. Can anyone have any idea about this error or how to draw the overlay on the whole screen of the phone including the status bar.

Here is my code I'm using to draw the overlay in the service onCreate method:

```
val windowManager = getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
val params = WindowManager.LayoutParams(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE           or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
        )
        windowManager.addView(GlowingBorderView(this), params)
```

It is working fine for the area where my application display but it is not going all the way up to the status bar of the phone.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help !

```
    private void addViewToWindowManager(View displayView) {
    //Should not use width(height) = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT to full screen
    WindowManager windowManager = ((WindowManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE));
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            ScreenUtils.getScreenWidth(),
            //WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ScreenUtils.getScreenHeight() + ScreenUtils.getNavigationBarHeight(this) + ScreenUtils.getStatusBarHeight(this),
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH
                    //blurred(dim) behind
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS
            , PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    //blurred(dim) behind value 0.0 to 1.0
    params.dimAmount = 1.0f;

    forceTransparentAndHideNavigationBar(displayView);
    windowManager.addView(displayView, params);
}
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76279754/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).